# how to calculate WOE for a dataset with weights column for both continuous and categorical data

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas, weighted

I want to calculate Weight of Evidence for a dataset with weights. I understand the ln(% of events/% of non-events) but how does it apply for data with weights and bins?

One way I thought that may or may not work is assuming weights column to be the bins.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.